# Ruby Net::Telnet not working with Proxy

Tags: ruby, telnet

I am trying to verify some emails using ruby's `Net::Telnet` class. For this, I connect to the SMTP server and execute a list of commands to verify if an email is correct. When used without proxies, it works fine.

Here is the code for when no proxy is used:

```
telnet = Net::Telnet.new('Host' => 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com' ,
'Port' => 25, 'Prompt' => /[$%#>] z/n, 'Timeout' => 10, "Telnetmode"
=> false) {|c| print c}

telnet.cmd("helo 97.74.230.16")


RESPONSE -  

mx.google.com at your service220
mx.google.com ESMTP q5-v6si5760178pgc.620 - gsmtp 250
```

When I use proxy:

```
proxy = Net::Telnet.new('Host' => '97.74.230.16', 'Port' => '59230',
"Telnetmode" => false) {|c| print c}

telnet = Net::Telnet.new('Host', 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com' , 'Port' => 25, 'Prompt' => /[$%#>] z/n, 'Timeout' => 10, "Proxy" =>
proxy, "Telnetmode" => false) {|c| print c}

telnet.cmd("helo 97.74.230.16")

RESPONSE -

[ => "\u0000[\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

I am not sure what is happening and why I am getting such a weird response.

What difference does it make to add a proxy? Am I using proxy in a wrong way?

Comment: Does the proxy needs some kind of login?

Comment: I don't think so. I am picking proxies from https://www.socks-proxy.net/

Comment: Ok.  I would check the following.  0) Try it with simple `ping` first to see if you get any reply at all 1) Does gmail SMTP allow such proxing?  (It could have such proxies on blacklist).  2) I would test it on proxy under my control so I could monitor all sides of connections on proxy and on client via wireshark.  3) check STMP relay

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try these once, but i am skeptic what is causing these weird responses that i am unable to understand and debug. Let you know after I try.

Comment: You are welcome.  It is hard to help if you know only the output and you can't "touch" the connection.